# "Invalid user identity in provided tenant" when sending adaptive card to other members in meeting

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am building a Teams app that uses a notification bot to send an Adaptive Card to each member of a meeting. The code is essentially unchanged from the example code created by the Teams Toolkit:

```
for (const target of await bot.notification.installations()) {
    if (target.type === "Group") {
        const members = await target.members()
        for (const member of members) {
            await member.sendAdaptiveCard(<<adaptive card details>>)
        }
    }
}
```

It has no issue sending the card to the meeting creator, but for any other members, it throws the error message:

`The bot encountered an unhandled error: Invalid user identity in provided tenant`

I've tried logging the member objects, and there doesn't seem to be any missing or broken information. The other member definitely has their own tenantId. At this point, I'm at a loss for what the issue could be, since this is basically just using the provided code.

Comment: As far as i remember...and this is vaguely as its been a while...there are two types of ID's internal and external, you might just have the wrong id here. Need to find the details about that.

Comment: @David - Could you please share which document or sample you are referring for this?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT This is from the VSCode Teams Toolkit. If you use it to create a Teams app, and select the notification bot type, the code is generated in the bot/src/index.js file. There's also a screenshot of the same code block in the README. I can't find an online reference that has the code, but if you follow the steps in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/create-new-project), that generates the code.

Comment: @DavidCooksley -  Looks like you are trying to send the Adaptive Card to the person who doesn't belong to that particular tenant. Meeting participants should exists in your tenant otherwise you want be able to send the card/messages.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Thanks for the answer! To clarify, the tenant is the organization right? So if everyone in the meeting is in the same organization as the creator, it should work?

Comment: Yes, correct. Because if you have configured the application for a tenant, you won't be able to send messages to another tenant users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being that the bot can only send Adaptive Cards to users within the host's tenant/organization. Adding this if statement prevents the error:

```
for (const target of await bot.notification.installations()) {
    if (target.type === "Group") {
        const members = await target.members()
        for (const member of members) {
            if (member.account.tenantId === target.conversationReference.conversation.tenantId) {
                await member.sendAdaptiveCard(<<adaptive card details>>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it does successfully send the card to members within the host tenant.